# Copy directory and assign destination ownership to directory and contents

Tags: linux, unix

I am using `cp -rp` command to copy a directory `/test` to the directory `public_html`, preserving the destination ownership, like this:

```
cp -rp /home/test/ /home/user/public_html/test
```

As expected, the directory `/test` is copied to `/home/user/public_html/test` but only the `/test` directory is preserving destination ownership. All other files inside `/test` has the `root:root` ownership:group.

I also tried the `-a` option:

```
cp -a /home/test/ /home/user/public_html/
```

But the issue persists.

How do I do so the all the files and subdirectories inside the copied `/test` folder also have the destination ownership?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve, and what the described scenario has to do with most of your tags. If the tags don't really apply (you're not developing a device driver) the question is off-topic as it's not a programming problem.

Comment: @tink can you please help?

Comment: If I could understand what the actual issue you're trying to solve in terms of programming is, maybe? I see no correlation between the question and most of the tags you applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment to ask this, but it might also serve as an answer. Can you use rsync? In its default state it will copy files over but not change target permissions. If you wanted to preserve source permissions you could use the -p flag. Note that you’ll need a combination of flags to manage recursive copy and such.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: I use `rsync -a /home/test /home/user/public_html` and literally only the copied directory `/home/user/public_html/test/` results with the destination ownership, its subfolders and files inside still have the `root:root` ownership... any idea why?

Comment: If they are newly added files then they will always have source ownership. In your case, using the -a flag is making rsync function with a variety of flags, including the -p flag which is preserving source permissions. Check the man page for the correct list, but I think -a is equivalent to something like `-rlptgoD`. You'll want to replace `rsync -a` with `rsync -rltgoD` to get the same effect as -a but without the source permission functionality. HTH!

Comment: @sea003 I tried `rsync -rltgoD /home/test /home/user/public_html` and still only `/home/user/public_html/test` has the destination ownership but not its contents, the contents have the source ownership, any other thought???

Comment: Thank you all, it was accomplished with  `chmod -R --reference=some-file` command